# Is there a way to move down one directory in ms-dos(cmd)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

Is there a way to move down one directory using ms-dos? i.e scripts and batch files. Like i know you can move up one directory using ..\ but i need to move down one directory without knowing the name of the directory. Is there a command for that?

so if i was in 
c:\new
i want a command that will get me to 
c:\new\test\testing

without using the name test

Thanks

Comment: What if there are multiple directories below `C:\new`, then what?

Comment: directly on the command line, use command completion: type `cd ` and press  `TAB`. For scriptable solutions, see dbenham's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move up a directory, there can only be one parent. So it makes sense to have a convenient method to do this - `CD ..`

But when you move down there can be any number of children to move to. How can you possibly know which one to move to if you don't know the name?

It is easy to iterate the children directories, at which point you could CD for example. You can use GOTO to break out of the loop so that you arbitrarily go to the first folder found.

```
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  cd "%%F"
  goto :break
)
:break
```

Comment: i see what your are saying, but in my situation i only have one child folder which name is a version number and inside that folder is the content i want to access. so i just need to skip that version number folder basically since it can be a variable value

Comment: @Bullsfan127, this version `for /d %%a in (*) do cd "%%a"` will change into the 1st directory found (avoiding `.` and `..`)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a short path to get there, IF you have ONLY one directory in the intermediate directory/directories, you can use this:

Example 1:

```
The path is new/test/testing

new
└── test
    └── testing

You can do:

cd new/*/testing          # to get the directory "testing"
```

Example 2:

```
THe path is 1/2/3/4/5   
1
└── 2
    └── 3
        └── 4
            └── 5

You can do: 

cd 1/*/*/*/*         # to get the directory "5"
```

Comment: `cd` in `cmd` (or `MSDOS`) does not support any wildcards.